# Using sed to find and replace node version in certain files

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed to replace node version matches in certain files

The following is what I have come up with but it leaves certain digits or characters after replacement and is not replacing the whole match and is rather pretending the replacement to the existing text.

```bash
find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/nodejs\d*.x/nodejs18.x/" {} \;
```

currently the above does not work at all

Sample:

```
module "lambda_function" {
  source                 = "git::ssh://git@github.com/pizzahutuk/infra-module-lambda?ref=v4.5.11"
  runtime                = "nodejs16.x"
}
```

In the above example `nodejs16.x` should be changed to `nodejs18.x`

Comment: Is this a structured document written in HCL?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes

Comment: @JJoao Although the dot  in `nodejs[0-9]*.x` would match the dot given OP's example, in the regex context it means *any character*, but what needs to be matched is a *literal* dot, so it should be `nodejs[0-9]*\.x`.

Comment: Kusalananda gave you the correct solution, but just FYI, `sed` doesn't understand `\d` which is a PCRE feature. So `\d` in `sed` is just the letter `d` and nothing else. So that's why your approach didn't work, `sed` was looking for `nodejs` followed by 0 or more `d` characters, then any character (`.`) and an `x` and since you have numbers after the `nodejs` string, that wouldn't match.

Comment: @terdon And (or) they are using the native `sed` on macOS, which treats `-i` differently. It's unfortunately quite unclear what "does not work at all" actually means here, so we are left guessing and trying to cover all possible ways things could possibly have gone wrong.

Comment: Well, in either case, @Kusalananda, the regex wouldn't match so nothing would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Using [the HCL processor `hclq` from Matthew Olenik](https://github.com/mattolenik/hclq) (`mattolenik` on Github) (install with e.g. `go install github.com/mattolenik/hclq@latest`):

```bash
$ hclq set -i file module.lambda_function.runtime nodejs18.x
module "lambda_function" {
  source  = "git::ssh://git@github.com/pizzahutuk/infra-module-lambda?ref=v4.5.11"
  runtime = "nodejs18.x"
}
```

This reads the HCL document from the file called `file`. It sets the value of the `runtime` key to `nodejs18.x` when this key occurs in the `lambda_function` module.  If you used `--in-place`, the modification would be done in-place.

You may relax the query path by using a wildcard character:

```bash
$ hclq -i file set 'module.*.runtime' nodejs18.x
module "lambda_function" {
  source  = "git::ssh://git@github.com/pizzahutuk/infra-module-lambda?ref=v4.5.11"
  runtime = "nodejs18.x"
}
```

You may also use `set replace` to only replace specific strings:

```bash
$ hclq -i file set replace 'module.*.runtime' nodejs16.x nodejs18.x
module "lambda_function" {
  source  = "git::ssh://git@github.com/pizzahutuk/infra-module-lambda?ref=v4.5.11"
  runtime = "nodejs18.x"
}
```

In the above command, the `runtime` key's value would not be replaced with `nodejs18.x` unless it had the original value `nodejs16.x`.

Applying this to all files in the current directory and below could be done with `find`:

```bash
find . -type f -exec hclq -i {} --in-place set replace 'module.*.runtime' nodejs16.x nodejs18.x \;
```

If you would rather use `sed` to replace any occurrence of any NodeJS string, you may use

```bash
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/nodejs[0-9]*\.x/nodejs18.x/' {} +
```

This assumes you have a `sed` that understands the `-i` option as shown (FreeBSD and macOS use `-i ''` for in-place editing with no backup file). The `\d` thing you tried to use in your question is a Perl-compatible regular expression pattern, also supported by GNU regular expressions. For portability, use either `[0-9]` as shown above, or `[[:digit:]]`. I escaped the dot in the pattern to match a literal dot instead of "any character", which the special `.` pattern usually matches.

Comment: is it possible to make the regex option non system dependent?

Comment: In GNU `sed` 4.7, `\d097` matches byte 97 (decimal), same as `\x61` (`a` in ASCII). In ast-open's `sed`, `\d` matches a decimal digit like in perl

Comment: @xerxes Yes, use POSIX basic regular expressions (my answer does that), and don't use `-i` (write the output to a new file and then move that to the original file, is one way of doing that).